# Function to add static values to a pandas series, up to a certain value, but still react to changes based on a given columns value

Tags: python, pandas, function, for-loop, cumulative-sum

I was able to create exactly what I wanted as a for loop going through a pandas dataframe. However, it's very slow once applied to even a small dataset (1000s of rows).

The beginning data frame is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = np.random.randint(low=0, high=2, size=(50, 2))
df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=['Column 1', 'Column 2'])


def my_signal(df):

    if ((df['Column 1']) - (df['Column 2'])) < 0:

        return 1

    else:

        return 0

df['signal'] = df.apply(my_signal, axis=1)

print(df.head())
```

Which produces the following output

```
   Column 1  Column 2  signal
0         1         0       0
1         0         0       0
2         1         1       0
3         0         1       1
4         0         0       0
```

Now I'd like to run through the data and if the signal is 0 then we return -0.2 and if its 1 we return 0.2 for our position. We'd also like to having a running total, called 'new col'.

```
def my_pos(df):

    if df['signal'] == 1:

        return 0.2

    else:

        return -0.2

df['position'] = df.apply(my_pos, axis=1)

df['new col'] = df['position'].cumsum()

print(df.head())


   Column 1  Column 2  signal  position  new col
0         0         0       0      -0.2     -0.2
1         0         0       0      -0.2     -0.4
2         1         0       0      -0.2     -0.6
3         0         1       1       0.2     -0.4
4         0         0       0      -0.2     -0.6
```

But now we get to the problem. We don't want the total position value to exceed 1 or be less than -1. I've tried using clip but what happens is that just caps the value displayed and while the 'new col' value still exceeds negative one. Here's an example of what we don't want to happen as we progress through the data

```
       Column 1  Column 2  signal  position   new col
20         0         0       0      -0.2         -0.8
21         0         0       0      -0.2         -1.0
22         1         0       0      -0.2         -1.0
23         0         0       0      -0.2         -1.0
24         0         1       0       0.2         -1.0
```

So in last row even though position was 0.2 our 'new col' value didn't change. But that's because at the 'new col' 23rd index value the value is actually -1.4, but appears as 1.0. So when we add 0.2 it still returns 1.0 because the value is -1.2, still less than -1.

I've been able to create a for loop to accomplish this, but as a mentioned it's very slow. I have to add a new column beforehand, but here's the loop:

```
df['new col'] = 0

for i in range(len(df)):

if df['signal'].iloc[i] == 0:   # if the signal is negative

    if ((df['new col'].iloc[i - 1]) - 0.2) < -1:   # if the row above - 0.1 < -1 set the value of current row to -1

        df['new col'].iloc[i] = -1

    else:   # if the new col value above -0.2 is > -1 then subtract 0.1 from that value

        df['new col'].iloc[i] = df['new col'].iloc[i - 1] - 0.2

elif df['signal'].iloc[i] == 1:     # if the signal is positive

    if ((df['new col'].iloc[i - 1]) + 0.2) > 1:     # if the value above + 0.1 > 1 set the current row to 1

        df['new col'].iloc[i] = 1

    else:   # if the row above + 0.2 < 1 then add 0.1 to the value of the current row

        df['new col'].iloc[i] = df['new col'].iloc[i - 1] + 0.2
```

I'm thinking the main source of my problem is being able to reference each previous value within the function. But I'm not sure. At the end of the day my question would be how produce the output from the above for loop in a much more efficient way to my pandas dataframe.

Thanks!